# Ошибка при импорте глобальных стилей

Tags: css, reactjs, scss, nextjs

Есть `/component`, где лежит

```
general.module.css
```

Выглядти он примерно так:

```
import "../style/color.scss"
import "../style/debug.css"


.grid-item-menu {
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    background: $item-color;
}
```

В этом `general.module.css`. Я хочу импортировать глобальные стили, которые лежат в

```
/styles/debug.css
```

, наппример. А также,

```
/styles/color.scss
```

На что я получаю ошибку

```
[ error ] ./components/general.module.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader??__nextjs_postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-3-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-3-4!./components/general.module.scss)
SassError: expected selector.
  ╷
1 │ import "../style/text.scss"
  │        ^
  ╵
  /home/eurvanov/react/adeo-dataplatform-dictionaries/components/general.module.scss 1:8  root stylesheet
```

Как побороть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Две проблемы есть.

1. `import` делается [иначе](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import). Правильно делать так `@import`
2. Указан ошибочный путь из-за чего оказывается невозможным сделать импорт `"../styles/color.scss"`, а не `"../style/color.scss"`